# Detect tap on "no displayed search results" in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a standard iOS UITableView with UISearchBar. It all works fine. I've implemented a method that hides the search bar when a user taps the Cancel button by implementing the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` delegate method. That's all good.

But here's my question:

When a user taps the search button, and does not search for anything, no delegate method is called when he/she taps on the dimmed out space where no search results are displayed. You know which space I mean? The one that would either display "no results" or the search results. When no text is entered into the search bar, this dimmed out space is empty - and reacts to a user's touch (dismissing the searching table view).

Is there a delegate method associated with this touch event? Or is there a workaround to detect this particular touch?

You can examine my code on GitHub: https://github.com/versluis/Table-Seach-2013

Here's a screenshot to illustrate:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
```

Comment: I've already tried that. My class conforms to the UISearchDisplayDelegate protocol, but the method is never called - not even when the search actually ends.

Comment: it does get called, makes sure you're setting yourself as delegate like self.searchController.delegate = self. Do that in viewWillAppear or something

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
```